# Angularjs, Redirect views from controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularJS. I'm using angularjs to implement a website. The website has two pages. The first page list all items and if user click on it, it will redirect to detail information page.

I have my routes configure as below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/list", {
        templateUrl : "list.html",
        controller  : "listCtrl"
    })
    .when("/detail/:id"){
        templateUrl : "detail.html"
    }
});
```

In the list.html. I use ng-repeat to display a list of items and a listener on to listen mouse click.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.name}}
      <a href="#" ng-click="goToEdit($index)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to redirect view to detail information in the ng-click function.
I tried    `$location.path()` but it not working.

```
$scope.goToEdit = function(index){
      console.log($location.path());
      $location.path("/detail/" + index);
      console.log($location.path());
}
```

This way won't work.
Even though the second log on console show location.path() has been changed to " /detail/id".

If I add `$scope.$apply()` after `$location.path();` Then I will get a action already in progress error.

Do you have any solution???

Thanks

Comment: let me see your controller, what are you injecting?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a Plunker?

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with use `href="#"` which is not good when using hash based routing

You could just set the href yourself and don't really need the controller function or `ng-click`

```
<a ng-href="#/detail/{{$index}}" >
```

Note that you should really give each item a unique identifier as $index could change due to using filters in ng-repeat or removing data from array

Also you don't have a controller identified for your second route

Comment: Becomes a pain if you're using HTML5 mode, then you don't need the `#` prefix. Another reason why I like ui.router better

Comment: @Phil totally agree `ui-sref` makes it much simpler and html5Mode agnostic

Comment: Using `$location.path` should be HTML5 mode agnostic too. I can't see a reason for OP's code not to work

Comment: @Phil agree unless the hash is wigging out ngRoute ...easy enough to preventDefault too I guess

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't think of that. It probably is just redirecting to `#` from the `href`.